# Do bind mounts from NFS path create additional connections to the underlying NFS server?

Tags: linux, centos, nfs, tcp, bind-mount

I am designing the following setup:

NFSv3 server

Centos7 Client

The client mounts an NFS share from the server to /mnt/nfs_share

Now I want to create many read only bind mounts from that mount to inner directories.
e.g:

```
mount --bind /mnt/nfs_share/dir1 /svc/dir1
mount --bind /mnt/nfs_share/dir2 /svc/dir2
...
...
...
mount --bind /mnt/nfs_share/dirN /svc/dirN
```

My question is - does this create network and connection overhead on the NFS server? or the same single mount is used to communicate with the NFS server, and all the bind mounts are local, without creating additional tcp connections?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the traffic using for example Wireshark while you do something like touching a file?

Comment: I'm running 'netstat -nap' grepping the IP of the nfs server.

I only see the single established TCP connection when initiating the bind mount, or opening / reading files.

however if I unmount the bind mount, I see an additional TCP connection to the NFS server in TIME_WAIT.

Worth to mention that if I do a normal mount to the NFS (I see multiple new connections, mountd, statd, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

I've ran a tcpdump to capture incoming/outgoing traffic to the IP of the NFS server, and it looks like the existing original mount port is being re-used for any communication done via the bind mount, which is good!